Chanting only a part of Chandipath
In chandipath there is a hymn I recall which goes like this ya Devi sarva bhuteshu Shakti rupena sananstitha namastesya namastesya namastesya namo namaha and there are many qualities of deities which are chanted. I wanted to know what is the name of the complete hymn and what are the rules to chant only the hymn and not the entire Durga saptashati. Also can we get any benefits by chanting only the hymn or is it a must to chant the  entire Durga shapta shati? Thank you.
